# Colocar font externa em site

Tags: html, css-font-face, font

Eu tenho uma font que preciso de pôr no site (edosz.ttf), estive a pesquisar e acabei com este código:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "edosz";
  src: url('edosz.ttf');
}
```

mas não dá! Alguém me podia ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Para adicionar uma fonte ao seu site você utilizará a regra do css chamada `@font-face`.

[Suporte dos navegadores para: @font-face](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface).

```
@font-face{
    font-family: NomeDaFonte;

    /*Caso a fonte esteja na mesma pasta*/
    src: url("ArquivoDaFonte.eot");
}
```

Lembrando que o caminho depende do local do arquivo.

```
 @font-face{ 
    /*Caso a fonte esteja dentro de uma pasta*/
     src: url("/pasta/ArquivoDaFonte.eot");

    /*Caso a fonte esteja na pasta anterior*/
     src: url("../ArquivoDaFonte.eot");
}
```

Caso queira checar se o usuário possui a fonte instalada em seu sistema:

```
@font-face {
    src: local(ArquivoDaFonte.eot), url(ArquivoDaFonte.eot);
}
```

As fontes possuem alguns formatos.

**TrueType** - .ttf

*format('embedded-opentype')*

---

**OpenType** - .ttf, .otf

*format('embedded-opentype')*

[Suporte dos navegadores para: TTF/OTF](https://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf).

---

**TrueType with Apple Advanced Typography extensions** - .ttf

*format('embedded-opentype')*

---

**Embedded OpenType** - .eot

*format('embedded-opentype')*

É o formato que deixa o @font-face compatível com  o IE7/8/9.

[Suporte dos navegadores para: EOT](https://caniuse.com/#feat=eot).

---

**SVG Font** - .svg, .sgvz

*format('embedded-opentype')*

[Suporte dos navegadores para: SVG](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts).

---

**WOFF2** - .woff2

*format('woff2')*

Traz uma redução de aproximadamente 30% do tamanho do arquivo.

[Suporte dos navegadores para: WOFF2](https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2).

---

Caso precise de um conversor eu utilizo este aqui: [Everything Fonts](https://everythingfonts.com/font-face)

Exemplo de suporte mais intenso aos browsers.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NomeDaFonte';
    src: url('ArquivoDaFonte.eot'); /* IE9 */
    src: url('ArquivoDaFonte.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
        url('ArquivoDaFonte.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Browsers de ponta */
        url('ArquivoDaFonte.woff') format('woff'), /* Browsers atualizados */
        url('ArquivoDaFonte.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
        url('ArquivoDaFonte.svg#NomeDaFonte') format('svg'); /* iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para o código abaixo, a fonte deve estar na mesma pasta do arquivo CSS, caso esteja em um diretório diferente é necessário referência-lo corretamente.

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "edosz";
  src: url('edosz.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alem do código do `font-face` é necessário você atribui-lo a algum seletor no css como:

Seu @font-face

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "edosz";
  src: url('edosz.ttf');
}
```

Atribuindo a nova fonte a um elemento da página:

```
body {
    font-family: edosz;
}
```